# How do I use this as a mouse?

Tags: mouse

What am I supposed to do when the battery runs out and this happens?

What's the best work-around for this problem as I've been caught out by it?

[image: mouse]

Comment: Questions require a problem to be solved. This seems more like “this stinks, am I right?” Which is better for [chat] or a discussion forum. See [ask] and the part about [avoiding opinion and open ended questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a bit rubbish, but by asking, one can learn surprising things! Maybe I'm missing something genuinely useful and intelligent.

Comment: Join us in [chat] - let's see if an edit can be made so it's more about doing something - a problem to be solved that's on topic here.

Comment: You could change the question to ask "how can I use this mouse while it is being charged?", but that is equally pointless.  The question is really just a rant and should be deleted.

Comment: Actually there was a practical problem, it ran out of battery without warning me, so using it while it was like this would have been handy knowledge

Comment: edited, because actually this is a problem, even though my title was facetious

Comment: This is a known issue: [Apple Customer Reviews](https://www.apple.com/shop/reviews/MLA02LL/A/magic-mouse-2).  I dumped the "magic" mouse and got a Logitech MX Performance and haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 1):

Have a break and enjoy a cup of coffee :-)

I usually keep an eye out for the "battery low" warnings my Mac throws at me when the keyboard battery runs low and make extra sure to plug it in at the end of the day then.